# Testing whether new variables improve XGBoost model

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

I have built an XGBoost model using different financial ratios in order to predict bankruptcy. My model yielded an AUC of approximately 0.8. Now I want to add 12 more non-financial variables and test whether the new variables individually and/or all together improve the XGBoost model. My questions are:

- Is it sufficient to compare AUC (e.g. average AUC based on 5-folds for each of the two models) before and after adding the variables in order to check for overall improvement? Could I further on, based on AUC confidence intervals, conclude upon whether the model has improved or not?
- If I want to also check the importance of every individual variable, would the variable importance of the two models be useful or should I experiment with different statistical methods testing significance?

Thanks!